# voice recording using pyaudio not working as expected

Tags: audio-recording, pyaudio

This is the code I wrote to record my audio until I stop the program and save it in output.wav. The problem is that the output.wav is all silent and when I print the frames, they are all zeros. I am running it on Mac OS. I tried recording an audio using the Mac voice recorder and it works so there shouldn't be a problem with the microphone, I guess. Any suggestions why that is the case?

```
import pyaudio
import wave

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100


def record():
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                    channels=CHANNELS,
                    rate=RATE,
                    input=True,
                    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

    print("Start recording")

    frames = []

    try:
        while True:
            data = stream.read(CHUNK)
            frames.append(data)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Done recording")
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))

    sample_width = p.get_sample_size(FORMAT)

    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()

    return sample_width, frames


def record_to_file(file_path):
    wf = wave.open(file_path, 'wb')
    wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
    sample_width, frames = record()
    wf.setsampwidth(sample_width)
    wf.setframerate(RATE)
    wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
    wf.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('#' * 80)
    print("Please speak word(s) into the microphone")
    print('Press Ctrl+C to stop the recording')

    record_to_file('output.wav')

    print("Result written to output.wav")
    print('#' * 80)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running this code on my Windows 10 machine and python 3.7 produced an audio file. Make sure that your microphone is [enabled](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/control-access-to-your-microphone-on-mac-mchla1b1e1fe/mac) on your mac